# Postgres: merge 2 database into another one using dumps

Tags: postgresql

I am in a situation to merge 2 (in future more) postgres databases (db1 and db2) into a new one (dbM) that have the same schema of the previous two.
db1=300Gb and db2=524Gb
I did a pg_dump parallel backup using -Fd (format directory) for both of them.
Since the fact that I cannot use insert statement (I lose parallel working) and it is too slow compared to format directory. There is a way to use both dumps?
Taking into account that could be a duplicate tuples in both of databases.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "Taking into account that could be a duplicate tuples in both of databases" -- does that mean you don't want both copies of the tuples in the resulting database?

Comment: Thanks for answering me, yes I don't want because duplicate tuples have the same primary key values, and when the DBMS find duplicates on PK, it rollback the whole process of copy&importing

Comment: 1) Create&Insert them into two separate schemas within the same database. 2) Then, merge these, table by table, handling the duplicates as you go. 3) If there are serials involved, some extra non-trivial work (re-keying) may be needed.